# Vapor App deployed to AWS gets stuck after high load

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I have my Vapor 3 Swift app deployed to AWS inside a Docker container. I was following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-swift-web-applications-with-amazon-ecs/) instruction and the app was deployed successfully. Additionally, I have RDS PostgreSQL database running on the same AWS account.

Everything was OK until we made some performance testing using **Artillery**. For some unknown reason the backend gets totally frozen after some amount of Artillery requests (around 1000) - it doesn't respond to any request. I don't have any warnings or errors in the EC2 Console - everything is fine, according to the metrics.

This seems not to be a Database problem because at the same time I run the Vapor locally, connected to the same RDS DB and everything works fine. However, there's this line constantly appears in the **Database Logs**:

> FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command

I'm not sure if this causes the whole problem because, as I mentioned, it perfectly works locally. No other errors are presented in logs. When I stop the task and run it again the backend gets back to work.

Is it the subtleties of the AWS? I would very appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increment file descriptors for swift process. In supervisor config file add

```
minfds=1048576
```

under supervisord section.